# Python TypeError: take_one() missing 1 required positional argument: 'state'

Tags: python

Here's the code:

```
from tkinter import *

class Main_content:
    def take_one(self, state):
        state = state - 1
        return self.state

    def take_two(self, state):
        state = state - 2
        return self.state

    def __init__(self, master, state):
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()

        self.label_status = Label(frame, text = "Coins left: " + str(state))
        self.label_status.pack()
        self.label_status = Label(frame, text = "Player " + str(player) + " turn's")
        self.label_status.pack()

        self.pak_een = Button(frame, text="Take 1 coin", command=self.take_one)
        self.pak_een.pack()
        self.pak_twee = Button(frame, text="Take 2 coins", command=self.take_two)
        self.pak_twee.pack()

root = Tk()

player = 1
state = 21
b = Main_content(root, state)

root.mainloop()
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Freddie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1550, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: take_two() missing 1 required positional argument: 'state'
```

I am new so I can't figure out what I do wrong. I don't know what that means.

Comment: Buttons don’t send events or other arguments to their command-handlers. Where should your argument "state" come from?

Comment: @DeepSpace Why do you remove traceback tag and python3 tag? There are not useful?

Comment: @Stargateur This error is not Python3 specific, and the traceback tag isn't relevant to this question.

Answer (score 2):

There are some issues:

1. `take_one` and `take_two` methods expect an argument `state`, but you never pass them that argument.
2. `self.state` that you are trying to return in these functions is never defined, anywhere.
3. Even if the rest of the code worked, the lines `state = state - 1` and `state = state - 2` are doing nothing useful. `state` is a local variable in these functions and is never returned or used.

You should store `state` that was passed to `__init__` in `self.state`, then the event handlers will have access to it and won't need to get it as an argument and they won't need to return it:

```
class Main_content:

    def take_one(self):
        self.state -= 1

    def take_two(self):
        self.state -= 2

    def __init__(self, master, state):
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()

        self.state = state
        self.label_status = Label(frame, text = "Coins left: " + str(self.state))
        self.label_status.pack()
        self.label_status = Label(frame, text = "Player " + str(player) + " turn's")
        self.label_status.pack()

        self.pak_een = Button(frame, text="Take 1 coin", command=self.take_one)
        self.pak_een.pack()
        self.pak_twee = Button(frame, text="Take 2 coins", command=self.take_two)
        self.pak_twee.pack()
```

If I'm following your logic you will also need to update the value of the label each time a button is pressed with the current value of `self.state`, I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader :)

Comment: yes, every time a player pressed a button than the label must be updated, but when i run this code it does nothing